# Is there a way to convert a list variable into a non-list variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Specifically, I've been trying to make a code that assigns the variable `my_list` to a non-list variable without any spaces or commas.

```
my_list= [3, 4, 5, 9]  # Has to be integers  
my_var= ' '  
...
```

Expected result at the end:

```
my_var = 3459
```

However, the problem is that I am able to do the complete opposite, and with letters instead:

```
variable = 'hello'  
mylist = [ ]  
for item in variable:  
    mylist.append(item)   
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to convert your list into a string. You can use `join()` for that:

```
my_var = ''.join(str(x) for x in my_list)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.
>   A `TypeError` will be raised if there are any non-string values in
>   iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is
>   the string providing this method.

---

Or using `map()`:

```
my_var = ''.join(map(str, my_list))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed,
>   function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items
>   from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator
>   stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

---

Similarly, if you want `my_var` to be an `int` just do `int(my_var)`

**Example:**

```
>>> my_list= [3, 4, 5, 9]
>>> my_var = ''.join(str(x) for x in my_list)
>>> my_var
'3459'
>>> int(my_var)
3459
>>> my_var = ''.join(map(str, my_list))
>>> my_var
'3459'
>>> int(my_var)
3459
```